# iOS - Execute code when application settings are changed

Tags: ios, settings-bundle

I am brand new to iOS development and finding it quite difficult to accomplish what I would think to be a fairly simple task.

I have an app that uses Parse push notifications and I would like to subscribe/unsubscribe from channels when the user makes a change to the app's preferences in the Settings application. All of the information that I have found shows how to synchronize settings once the app has been opened again but what I am hoping to accomplish is as follows:

1. User changes a toggle button for a particular channel in the Settings application - when they toggle it On, I want to subscribe. Off, unsubscribe
2. When the preference changes, I want to be able to call code in my app to take care of making the change on Parse BEFORE the user opens the app again

**The short question -** Is there any way to register a callback in the application when a preference is changed in Settings?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing to "call back". If the user is working in the Settings app, your app, *ex hypothesi*, is not running.

When your app becomes active once again, you get an event (`applicationDidBecomeActive`). Your job is to consult your NSUserDefaults to see if anything has changed, as I believe you already know.

If that isn't sufficient, then don't use a Settings bundle - provide subscribe/unsubscribe interface within your app itself.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thanks so much for the quick answer!